# FLASK - You have an error in your SQL syntax near '%(site_id)s' at line 1

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I' like to have a small explanation about Flask, Something I don't understand. I'm looking to get DATA from Database by an ID. The ID is my route parameter. 
I've create my route, but I'm having an error, And I don't understand What they are requesting in fact ? An element from Database ?

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%(site_id)s' at line 1

My route code :

```
    #Construct app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_object('secret_config')

#Database functions
def connect_db () :
    g.mysql_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],
        user = app.config['DATABASE_USER'],
        password = app.config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
        database = app.config['DATABASE_NAME']
    )

    g.mysql_cursor = g.mysql_connection.cursor()
    return g.mysql_cursor

    def get_db () :
        if not hasattr(g, 'db') :
            g.db = connect_db()
        return g.db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db (error) :
    if hasattr(g, 'db') :
        g.db.close()



@app.route('/historique/<int:site_id>')
def historique(site_id):

db = get_db()

db.execute('SELECT * FROM sites s JOIN historique h ON h.site_id WHERE `s.site_id = %(site_id)s', {'id': site_id})

entries = db.fetchall()
return render_template('historique.html',  entries = entries)
```

And Here is my HTML Code

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block titre %}
    Acceuil
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Historique d'activité pour  {{ entrie.0 }}</h1>
{% for entrie in entries %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I only like to understand. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: There's a spurious backtick character after `WHERE`. And that `s` following the closing paren doesn't look right to me. (Maybe that's something special for FLASK, but it doesn't look like valid SQL.) Also, the join predicate  doesn't look right to me... maybe we meant to write `ON h.site_id = s.site_id` ?  Have we *tested* the SQL in another client (like the mysql command line client), before we incorporated it into the app?

Comment: Please paste the whole traceback, not just a description of it. Also, what kind of database are you using? More generally, give us a [mcve], rather than just random fragments of code and output.

Comment: I've édit my first post, with My route from app.py and the elements above.
As database I'm using MySQL

Comment: @Newbiedev, I suppose that you do not use any additional library, but if you are interested, I can expand my answer and show how to avoid such problem using `SQLAlchemy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have a mistake when you are formatting your string with sql query.
Try this

```
@app.route('/historique/<int:site_id>')
def historique(site_id):
    db = get_db()
    query = 'SELECT * FROM sites s JOIN historique h ON h.site_id WHERE `s.site_id = {site_id}'.format(site_id=site_id)
    db.execute(query)
    # ... rest of the code ...
```

And yes, this backtick before `s.site_id` *is* very suspicious.